# Free JavaFX TranslateTransition for garbage collection

Tags: java, javafx, garbage-collection

Assuming the following code for an endless animation:

```
private void someMethod() {
    TranslateTransition trans = new TranslateTransition();
    trans.setNode(bgAnim);
    trans.setDuration(new Duration(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(10)));
    trans.setByX(100);
    trans.setByY(-500);
    trans.setOnFinished(event -> {
        // some code to change direction
        trans.play();
    });
    trans.play();
}
```

Now I am changing the screen, however the setOnFinished code is still executed in the other screen (I am using [this code](https://github.com/acaicedo/Screen-Framework/blob/master/src/multiplescreenframework/ScreenPane.java#L125) to change my screens). Is it not garabe collected due to it having a setOnFinished-Listener? Will calling trans.stop() allow the gc to collect it, or maybe trans = null?

The other elements of the screenController (like images) seem to be garbage collected. In VisualVM I can see memory being freed when I "spam click" the change screen button.

Comment: Sort-of off-topic: instead of using the `onFinished` handler to restart the animation, set the `cycleCount` to `Animation.INDEFINITE`. To make it auto-reverse, set `autoReverse` to true. AFAIK calling `stop()` and making sure it is out of scope will allow for gc.

Comment: @James_D Problem is that I need to call the following "                        bgAnim.setScaleX(bgAnim.getScaleX() * -1);" in order to turn the image around. So I kind of need setOnFinished anyways in this case right? Didn't include it in my demo code here, true

Comment: You could bind the scaleX property to the animation's `currentRate` property. Alternatively use a timeline instead of a translate transition and flip the scaleX in an event handler for the keyframe.

Comment: Sounds good as well, thanks